# Improve performance of deducting values of same table in SQL

Tags: sql

for a metering project I use a simple SQL table in the following format

- ID
- Timestamp: dat_Time
- Metervalue: int_Counts
- Meterpoint: fk_MetPoint

While this works nicely in general I have not found an efficient solution for one specific problem: There is one Meterpoint which is a submeter of another Meterpoint. I'd be interested in the Delta of those two Meterpoints to get the remaining consumption. As the registration of counts is done by one device I get datapoints for the various Meterpoints at the same Timestamp.

I think I found a solution applying a subquery which appears to be not very efficient.

```
SELECT 
A.dat_Time, 
(A.int_Counts- (SELECT B.int_Counts FROM tbl_Metering AS B WHERE B.fk_MetPoint=2 AND B.dat_Time=A.dat_Time)) AS Delta 
FROM tbl_Metering AS A 
WHERE fk_MetPoint=1
```

How could I improve this query?
Thanks in advance

Comment: if `fk_MetPoint`  is a _Foreign Key_, then are the values 1 and 2 constants? or just an example?

Comment: @Chris Schaller yes fk_MetPoint is indeed a Foreign Key and therefore 1 and 2 constants

Comment: Do you only have one meter or source that you are monitoring? your only link between the record and the duplicates is the time specifically, I was expecting another key, like meterID, or parent_Id with a self join (FK to the same table) what if 2 meters both happen to report readings at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a window function instead:

```
SELECT m.dat_Time, 
       (m.int_counts - m.int_counts_2) as delta
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN fk.MetPoint = 2 THEN int_counts END) OVER (PARTITION BY dat_time) as int_counts_2
      FROM tbl_Metering m
     ) m
WHERE fk_MetPoint = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From a query point of view, you should as a minimum change to a set-based approach instead of an inline sub-query for each row, using a group by as a minimum but it is a good candidate for a windowing query, just as suggested by [the "Great" Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467043/1690217)

However if this is a metering project, then we are going to expect a high volume of records, if not now, certainly over time.

I would recommend you look into altering the input such that delta is stored as it's own first class column, this moves much of the performance hit to the *write* process which presumably will only ever occur *once* for each record, where as your select will be executed many times.

This can be performed using an *INSTEAD OF* trigger or you could write it into the business logic, in a recent IoT project we computed or stored these additional properties with each inserted reading to greatly simplify many types of aggregate and analysis queries:

- Id of the Previous sequential reading
- Timestamp of the Previous sequential reading
- Value Delta
- Time Delta
- Number of readings between this and the previous reading

The last one sounds close to your scenario, we were deliberately batching multiple sequential readings into a single record.

---

You could also process the received data into a separate table that includes this level of aggregation information, so as not to pollute the raw feed and to allow you to re-process it on demand.

You could redirect your analysis queries to this second table, which is now effectively a data warehouse of sorts.